# Manually Calculating Joint Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Suppose you have a Normal Distribution where the mean is "0" and the variance is "1".

Suppose you want to find out the probability of this Normal Distribution generating the following sequences of numbers:

- **Sequence 1**: 0.9, 1.1, 1.9
- **Sequence 2:** 9, 6, 8

Using logic, Sequence 1 is more likely to have come from N ~ (0,1) compared to Sequence 2 (the numbers from Sequence 1 are closer to the mean of the normal distribution compared to the numbers from Sequence 2). However, I want to try and calculate the probability of both of these sequences.

For each sequence, the joint probability has the following form:

- P(x1, x2, x3) = P(x1 | N~(0,1) * P(x2 | N~(0,1) * P(x3 | N~(0,1)

Using the R programming language, I tried to calculate these manually:

```
small = 0.0001
```

**Joint Probability of Sequence 1 :**

```
integrate(dnorm, mean=0, sd=1, lower= 0.9 - small , upper=  0.9 + small, abs.tol = 0)$value * integrate(dnorm, mean=0, sd=1, lower= 1.1 - small , upper=  1.1 + small, abs.tol = 0)$value * integrate(dnorm, mean=0, sd=1, lower= 1.9 - small , upper=  1.9 + small, abs.tol = 0)$value 

[1] 3.042855e-14
```

**Joint Probability of Sequence 2 :**

```
integrate(dnorm, mean=0, sd=1, lower= 8 - small , upper=  8 + small, abs.tol = 0)$value * integrate(dnorm, mean=0, sd=1, lower= 9 - small , upper=  9 + small, abs.tol = 0)$value * integrate(dnorm, mean=0, sd=1, lower= 6 - small , upper=  6 + small, abs.tol = 0)$value 

[1] 2.524467e-52
```

As expected, Sequence 1 has a greater probability of being observed compared to Sequence 2.

**My Question:** Can someone please tell me if my calculations are correct? In general, is the math behind what I have done correct?

Thanks!

**References:**

- https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/Normal.html

Comment: What you calculated was not $P(x=x_1)$, which, as $x$ is a continuous random variable, would be $0$, but rather $P(x_1-\delta\leq x\leq x+\delta)$, with $\delta$ your ```small=0.0001```.

Comment: @patricio: thank you for your reply! In terms of practicality, is this approach (i.e.  small = 0.0001) correct? Thanks!

Comment: Don't take my word for it, but I don't think so. I think I'd compute the mean and the standard deviation of the two samples and see whether the fall in a "reasonable" confidence interval.

Comment: Following the logic of maximum likelihood techniques, you can calculate the product of $\phi(x)$ (the normal density given your 0,1 assumptions) for your two cases.  Comparing those probabilities will give you insight into which is more likely.  If one product gives 0.01 and the other gives 0.001 then you can say the first sequence is 10x more likely to see than the second.  This obviates the issue of $\delta$, if all you're doing is comparing two possibilities.